# Positive look-behind assertion and substitution with Vim?

Tags: regex, vim

I would like to use Vim to match a regular expression and perform a substitution. I have a tsv file with lines that look like this:

```
rs11223-A        -A
rs23300-G        -TTA
rs9733-T          -G
rs11900000-GT    -TTG
```

I wish to substitute the dash (-) character for a tab only in the first column after the rs...

In Vim I was attempting to perform the substitution using:

```
:%s/(?<=^rs[0-9]{1,12})-/\t/g
```

Could anyone point out what my problem is and a correct solution?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It may be dependent on configuration, but in my environment I have to prepend `{ , }` with `\`.

Also, Vim has `\zs` and `\ze` to start and end matching, so you usually don't have to deal with normal regex lookaround.

This does what you want:

```
:%s/^rs\d\{1,12}\zs-/\t/g
```

Answer (score 8):

Positive look behind is done using:

```
\@<=
```

So you could use something like:

```
:%s/\d\@<=-/\t/g
```

Your actual data may be more complex, but with what you posted you could also just settle for:

```
:%s/-/\t
```

If `rs` should be at the beginning of the line, you can use `\zs` to specify the start of the match and use anchoring (`^`):

```
:%s/^rs\d*\zs-/\t
```

Comment: #2 would have to be :%s/^rs\d\@<=-/\t/g

Comment: @KomodoDave: Your pattern would match `rs` at the beginning of the line, immediately followed by a dash (`-`) preceded by a *single* digit (positive look behind `\d\@<=-`). None of the lines in the data given matches that pattern. If you insist on anchoring you could use the pattern I just added.

Comment: I thought OP meant column in the sense of character columns, but maybe he doesn't. I copied yours to edit it and didn't replace \d with - as I intended - what I wanted to write is: :%s/^rs-\@<=/\t/g which matches '-' in the first char column after 'rs' at line start.

Answer (score 0):

You want the following:

```
%s/^\(rs[0-9]\{1,12\}\)-/\1\t/g
```

Vim regular expressions require some special escape sequences for `{`, `}`, `(` and `)`.

Also, in the substitution section, you need `\1` to insert your matched string.

Answer (score 0):

The correct expression to use lookbehind is:

```
%s/\(\d\+\)\@<=-/\t/gc
```

`\(\d\+\)\@<=` means to look behind positively to find digits (`\d\+` means to find at least one digits). According to [here](https://jbodah.github.io/blog/2016/11/01/positivenegative-lookaheadlookbehind-vim/), we have to capture `\d\+` before applying the positive look behind, hence the `\(\)` around `\d\+`.

Also, to use the normal regex `+` quantifier, we have to escape it in vim (`\+`), see [doc here](http://vimregex.com/#Non-Greedy).